# Integration twist

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \frac{4x^3(1+x^{8020})}{1+x^{8048}}dx$$
This question appeared in a mock test and since then I have been racking my brains how to do this.

My attempt: I tried replacing $x^4$ as $t$ and then substituting accordingly but after that I found it impossible to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Any hint too will at Least get me going. I am completely stuck

Comment: What do you mean by the many mock tests?

Comment: Are you familiar with the digamma function?

Comment: No but could you explain?

Comment: You have a factor $x^3$ and $8020,8048$ are divisible by $4$. You can simplify your integral.

Comment: $\int_0^1 \frac{4x^3(1+x^{8020})}{1+x^{8048}}dx=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+x^{8020})}{1+x^{8048}}dx^4=\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t^{2005})}{1+t^{2012}}dt$.

Comment: I have said this in my attempt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $x^4 \rightarrow v$ in your integral to get:
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{1+v^{2005}}{1+v^{2012}}\,dv$$
Now, $$\frac{1}{1+v^{2012}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kv^{2012k}$$
Put this in your integral to get:
$$I = \int_0^1 (1+v^{2005})\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kv^{2012k}\,dv$$
Interchanging the summation and integral, (Which is possible in this case, by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematical%20analysis%20Fubini%27s%20theorem,by%20using%20an%20iterated%20integral.&text=As%20a%20consequence%2C%20it%20allows,changed%20in%20certain%20iterated%20integrals.))
$$\implies I = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\int_0^1 (1+v^{2005})v^{2012k}\,dv$$
$$\implies I = \sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{1}{2012k+1} + \frac1{2012k + 2006}\right)$$
You can now use the [Digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) to simplify this, Use the representation:
$$\psi(1+x) = -\gamma + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \left(\frac1k - \frac1{k+x}\right)$$
To get $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\left(\frac1{k+x}\right) = \frac12 \left(\psi\left(\frac12 + \frac{x}2\right) - \psi\left(1 + \frac{x}2\right)\right) + \frac1x$$
And use this to simplify your expression.

Comment: What is the digamma function? Is it just a way of representation or it has some special properties?

Comment: It has a lot of great properties, check out the link in my answer!

Comment: a small note on *interchanging the summation and integration* : using this trick without knowing the concept is walking on thin ice...